# Query Oracle DB from SQL 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle

I have some ODBC connection information for an Oracle database, and I wanted to know if it is possible to query this database from SQL Server 2005?

Also, can I have a SQL job to extract data into my SQL DB?

Comment: CAN SOME ONE POINT ME TO SPECIFIC SAMPLES OF HOW TO SET THIS UP AND USE SQL TO PULL DATA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) will let you do this.

[SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) can also be used to extract the data

Answer (score 0):

I think you have enough information to set up a linked server. My practical experience showed some limitations, when it came to querying CLOB columns, but that seems to be a basic limitation of other tools based on OLEDB too. For special cases I use PowerShell scripts to extract data, which I do not get with the usual tools.